The relationship between the radii of the tangent circles of a parabola and the axis of symmetry
A little while ago I was using geogebra and I came up with a beautiful algebraic relationship in the parabola and the tangent circles to it

But I could not prove it, moreover the Euclidean creation of these circles is difficult and I have not been able to do it yet, in fact I have reached this relationship by creating a rough drawing of the composition.
If someone can explain how this can be constructed geometrically and in addition to that how to prove this algebraic relationship if it is true and thank you
If the algebraic relationship is known, please cite a source

How do you construct the blue circle which is simultaneously  tangent to both the parabola and the axis? It seems impossible to me.

Sorry, it's possible. I know where I went wrong now.

The fact is: they seem to satisfy such a beautiful formula, but they actually don't. I've deleted my answer because I think it's such a mess...

Experimenting with GeoGebra I found that your $4$ rather becomes $4.2$ when circle $B$ is small. I don't think that's a constant ratio.

I concur with others that the claimed relation does not hold.

Actually I realized I was wrong when it was late, indeed, the formula doesn't hold, it was the first time I tried to put an algebraic relationship without being able to do the geometric construction and that's where the problem started, I used to do engineering construction and then let Geogebra check equality, but now I've guessed the relationship with approximate drawings.

@زكرياحسناوي If you're interested in stacking circles in a parabola, then you may be interested in this.

I concur with others that the claimed relation does not hold.
Consider this GeoGebra sketch of a parabola with semi-latus rectum $p$:

The center of $\bigcirc A$, of radius $a$, lies at distance $a^2/2p$ from focus $F$. The (purple) parabola with focus $A$ and directrix tangent to the bottom point of $\bigcirc A$ is the locus of centers of circles tangent to $\bigcirc A$ and the parabola's axis.
The (green) quartic curve is the locus of centers of circles tangent to the parabola and its axis.
Point $C$ is the intersection of the two loci, and the radius $c$ of $\bigcirc C$ tangent to $\bigcirc A$, the parabola, and its axis, it determined.
We observe that the axis-centered circle of radius $4c-a$ tangent to $\bigcirc C$ is visibly quite distinct from the axis-centered circle of radius $4c-a$ tangent to the parabola, with a disparity seemingly too extreme to attribute to calculation error in GeoGebra. If OP's claim were valid, these circles would coincide. $\square$

You are right @Blue, thank you, I will stop estimating algebraic values in this way and go back to my previous geometric method

This is not an answer, but this is a partial build that may help with the construction we are looking for

The geometric position of point P is the parabolas shown in red
